# How to configure Flake8 with colcon test

Tags: ros2, colcon, ros-humble

When creating a package Ros2 automatically generates these tests: `test_copyright.py`, `test_flake8.py`, `test_pep257.py`. Running `colcon test` invokes these tests and that's fine if I'd be able to configure flake8 and pep257. According to the (somewhat scarce) documentation you can add a configuration file `~/.config/flake8` with for instance:

```
[flake8]
extend-ignore = E501
```

Or you can add configurations to a Ros2 package's `setup.cfg` file with for instance:

```
[flake8]
extend-ignore = E501
```

However, both options don't seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas how to configure these tools when running with `colcon test`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting `test_flake8.py` like underneath reads a `flake8.ini` file in the Ros workspace folder. Perhaps there's a cleaner way to find the ini file, but at least this works.

```
@pytest.mark.flake8
@pytest.mark.linter
def test_flake8():
    # Find flake8.ini in Ros workspace folder
    config_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent.parent / 'flake8.ini'
    rc, errors = main_with_errors(argv=['--config', str(config_path)])
    assert rc == 0, \
        f'Found {len(errors):d} code style errors / warnings:\n' + '\n'.join(errors)
```

Comment: Glad you found a way that works for you! The only thing I would suggest is the use of the `ament_index_python` package to get the directory and have the config installed instead referencing it to through the source directory. But I understand this way fully, since linting references only source anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled across this post having the same issue and question.

**However**, because I only installed some python executables in my package, I generated my workspace with the `ament_cmake` build type.

The auto generated test block in the `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()
```

The problem is that `ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()` [implicitly calls](https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/humble/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies.cmake#L34-L40) `ament_flake8` without a config file. (Not only flake8, but any other test dependency defined in the `package.xml`). To call it with a configuration file there are two ways with `ament_cmake` as the build tool.

1. Either set the global config path [as described here](https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/humble/ament_cmake_flake8/cmake/ament_flake8.cmake#L19-L25) like so (with the desired path, here it is the package source root directory):

```
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  set(ament_cmake_flake8_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.flake8")
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()
```

2. Or call the `ament_flake8` `cmake` function directly and pass the configuration file as an argument like so:

```
if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_cmake_flake8 REQUIRED)
  ament_flake8(CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.flake8")
endif()
```

### Setting up a project specific configuration

If there is a need to define only one configuration for a certain project, you can define a cmake macro and install it in a `common` package. This can be especially relevant if more configruations are commonly defined, like compiler flags, etc.

1. Create a package `my_project_common` and add a folder `cmake`. In that folder add a file called `my_project_package.cmake` and add the following lines:

```
macro(my_project_package)
    set(ament_cmake_flake8_CONFIG_FILE "your_project_specific_config_file_path")
endmacro()
```

2. Add another "extras" file called `my_project_common-extras.cmake` inside the root of your `common` project including your cmake macro file:

```
include("${my_project_common_DIR}/my_project_package.cmake")
```

3. In this common package `CMakeLists.txt` add the following lines:

```
install(
  DIRECTORY cmake
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package(
  CONFIG_EXTRAS "my_project_common-extras.cmake"
)
```

4. Now simply add this package to any of your package `CMakeLists.txt` and call the macro like so:

```
find_package(my_project_common REQUIRED)
my_project_package()
```

Hope this helps anybody.

Comment: Hi Nyquist, thanks for you answer. We're not using cmake indeed, so I also posted a solution that works for us. And I prefer one config file for the whole workspace, so our solution refers to an ini file in the Ros workspace folder.

Comment: @WouterOddBot - As you have done, you should post your own answer, rather than changing the solution provided by others. Different solutions work for different people. I hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: I posted my own answer, but also improved Nyquist's answer. It said 'to call the `cmake` function directly, but I think he meant 'to call the `ament_flake8` function directly, because that's what his example shows.

Comment: @WouterOddBot - yes, I did notice that, and must admit that it *is*, indeed, a bit confusing. However, the last line referring to `ament_cmake` *seems to imply* that it wasn't a typo. The best course of action (in this case, due to the ambiguity) is probably to leave a comment for Nyquist, asking for clarification and asking whether it is indeed a typo - rather than just editing the answer in the hope that it is a typo - if that makes sense..? :-)

Comment: `ament_cmake` is the build system calling the `CMakeList.txt` file that this code snippet is part of (as apposed to for instance the `ament_python` build system). When using `ament_cmake` one should replace in `CMakeList.txt` the call to `ament_auto_lint` with a direct call to `ament_flake8`.

Comment: And I expected that Nyquist would have to approve my edit anyway. That's why I thought it was fine to edit it. I hope he can clarify indeed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I clarified things and I actually had to remove a mistake. Clang format does not automatically find the configuration file. I don't know why I was thinking that. I also added a way of setting the configuration not globally but project wide as you wanted.